# SVG animation is not applied properly when a shape is moved

Tags: animation, svg, svg-animate

I'm trying to apply SVG animation to a triangle which is moved by (100, 100) pixels:

```html
<svg width="800" height="600">
    <polyline shapeId="triangle" fill="transparent" stroke="gray" points="0,0 52.5,160 105,0 0,0 " transform=" translate(100 100)">
    </polyline>
</svg>
```

I was expecting the triangle to be rotating around point (100, 100). However, the triangle is rotating around the origin of the SVG document:

```html
<svg width="800" height="600">
    <polyline shapeId="triangle" fill="transparent" stroke="gray" points="0,0 52.5,160 105,0 0,0 " transform=" translate(100 100)">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="0s" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" from="0" to="360"/>
    </polyline>
</svg>
```

If I specify rotation offset in the animation tag, the results are still not what I would expect: the triangle does not rotate around one of its corners.

```html
    <svg width="800" height="600">
        <polyline shapeId="triangle" fill="transparent" stroke="gray" points="0,0 52.5,160 105,0 0,0 " transform=" translate(100 100)">
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="0s" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100"/>
        </polyline>
    </svg>
```

What I want to achieve is triangle rotating around one of its cornered while moved by (100, 100) pixels.

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always transform a parent element...

```html
<svg width="800" height="600">
<g transform="translate(100 100)">
    <polyline shapeId="triangle" fill="transparent" stroke="gray" points="0,0 52.5,160 105,0 0,0 " >
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="0s" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" from="0" to="360"/>
    </polyline>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: So <polyline> is not considered the parent of the <animateTransform> ?

Comment: it is, but that's not really relevant here.

Comment: So is this behavior by design? I am trying to understand if <polyline>'s transform should change the coordinate system of <animateTransform>.